# How do you inject an angular2 service into a unit test? (RC3)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-testing, angular2-di

I am using `RC3`. I am implementing the new `Angular2` router as documented here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Everything works fine but I am having problem in unit testing. Specifically, I cannot inject `Angular2` services into my unit tests.

My relevant component code is:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: ...
  styleUrls: ...
})

export class Route1DetailComponent {

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(route);
  }
}
```

my unit test looks like:

```
import {
  expect, it, iit, xit,
  describe, ddescribe, xdescribe,
  beforeEach, beforeEachProviders, withProviders,
  async, inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Route1DetailComponent} from './route1-detail.component';
import {TestComponentBuilder} from '@angular/compiler/testing';

describe('route1-detail.component.ts', () => {

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: ActivatedRoute}
  ]);

  it('should instantiate component',
    async(inject([TestComponentBuilder, ActivatedRoute], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder, ar: ActivatedRoute) => {
      tcb.createAsync(Route1DetailComponent).then((fixture) => {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof Route1DetailComponent).toBe(true, 'should create Route1DetailComponent');
        console.log(ar);
    });
  })));
});
```

The 'should instantiate component' unit test fails. The error is:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ActivatedRoute'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
> Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have
> valid type annotations and that 'ActivatedRoute' is decorated with
> Injectable.

How do I get this working?

When I do not inject `ActivatedRoute` everything works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fcfddbf79cfbdca45771bb31c0a2c1f55cff5801/modules/%40angular/router/test/router.spec.ts might help

Comment: much appreciated still working on this very useful thx - more ideas welcome :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When unit testing, sometimes a certain service causes issues just because it's not being used in a normal environment. You can test to see if it has been called, without having the unit test run through the whole service. Do this by creating a mock class.

```
describe('route1-detail.component.ts', () => {

class MockActivatedRoute {}

beforeEachProviders(() => [
    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute}
  ]);

it('should instantiate component',
  async(inject([TestComponentBuilder, ActivatedRoute], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder, ar: MockActivatedRoute) => {
  tcb.createAsync(Route1DetailComponent).then((fixture) => {
    expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof Route1DetailComponent).toBe(true, 'should create Route1DetailComponent');
    console.log(ar);
  });
})));
```

Notice this part: `inject([TestComponentBuilder, ActivatedRoute], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder, ar: MockActivatedRoute`. When the code is looking for ActivatedRoute, you are passing it the mock service.
Of course if you are specifically trying to unit test ActivatedRoute itself, then creating a mock service defeats that purpose. You might have to add methods or variables to the mock class if it tries to call methods from that service.

Comment: Glad to help @danday74

Comment: This is great! How would you modify the MockActivatedRoute if you were using route paramters?

Comment: I have not tested this but you could try something like this so you can call a fake params from the mock route. It gets more complicated if you're also subscribing to params but I'm sure it could be done.
class MockActivatedRoute {
       params(){}
  }